# ¿como encontrar el tamaño real de un proyecto en GitLab desde línea de comandos?

Tags: git, gitlab

Estoy escribiendo un hook pre-receive para GitLab, basado en esta pregunta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791509/how-to-prevent-a-git-repository-growing-above-a-maximum-size?noredirect=1&lq=1), que bloquee las actualizaciones del repositorio en caso de que superen un tamaño límite.

El problema es que el comando que usan allí para saber el tamaño del repositorio (`git count-objects -v`), no me devuelve el tamaño real del repositorio.

Al comparar el tamaño que me devuelve ese comando, con el que muestra la API de GitLab, veo que la API de GitLab muestra un valor diferente (habitualmente superior) al que muestra este comando.

El tamaño mostrado por `git-count` en el pre-receive es este (ver línea de error)

[image: Tamaño mostrado por <code>git count</code> en pre-receive]

Mientras que GitLab muestra este otro tamaño

[image: Tamaño mostrado por GitLab]

Una forma de obtenerlo sería llamando a la propia API. 
Pero, para eso, necesitaría saber el nombre y propietario del proyecto en que me encuentro. Y no parece trivial

¿cómo podría obtener el tamaño real del proyecto?

Comment: Quizás no estoy entendido bien el problema, pero que los tamaños sean algo distintos es normal, si estás haciendo un push, se supone que hay objetos en tu repo local que no están en el remoto, deberían mostrar lo mismo después de hacer el push (o después de un clone)

Comment: En este caso, el push se ha rechazado. Y el `git count-objects` (el tamaño que se indica en el error) se está haciendo en el servidor. Así que el tamaño debería ser similar

Comment: Es posible que puedas arreglarlo con git gc o git repack con depth mayor a 50. Pero gitlab en particular tiene un ticket de hace un año https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/3429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, he descubierto el problema:

- El tamaño que muestra GitLab es una medida que se calcula en las estadísticas, pero no se actualiza en cada push, sino que se recalcula cada cierto intervalo de tiempo. Por lo tanto, el tamaño que GitLab muestra no siempre se corresponde con el tamaño real del repositorio
- Haciendo un `du -sb` en el directorio donde se ubica el repositorio en el servidor, puedo obtener el tamaño real de este (el cual corresponde con el que muestra GitLab tras su rastreo, pasado un tiempo). El pre-receive se ejecuta sobre ese mismo directorio, así que simplemente es cuestión de ejecutar el comando en el script.

  Pero, al calcularlo en el pre-receive, este tamaño también incluye el
  nuevo objeto que queremos subir.

Aún así, por el momento, me he quedado con el cálculo del tamaño mediante `du -sb`

Answer (score 4):

Probablemente la forma de calcular el tamaño en GitLab sea algo específica o propietaria, dependerá de factores que sólo conoce GitLab, sin embargo, una forma fiable de conocer cuánto ocupa el proyecto en gitLab es usando su propio API REST:

```
curl -XGET --header "Private-Token: <your_token>" "https://<your_instance>/api/v4/projects/<project_id>?statistics=true
```

La salida, entre otros datos, debe contener un objeto como este:

```
"statistics": {
  "commit_count": 37,
  "storage_size": 1038090,
  "repository_size": 1038090,
  "wiki_size" : 0,
  "lfs_objects_size": 0,
  "job_artifacts_size": 0,
  "packages_size": 0
},
```

Tienes más información en la doc dle API de projects: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

Comment: Si. Me lo he planteado. De hecho, tengo esa consulta adaptada a Python.
Pero, para hacer eso, necesito saber el nombre y propietario del repositorio donde me encuentro (dado que lo lanzo en un hook configurado para todos los repositorios)

Comment: Entiendo, pues la verdad no estoy seguro, estuve mirando la doc y no queda claro, ¿ has probaddo a comprobar la ruta/path donde se ejecuta el hook ? Es posible que el usuario y el project sean parte de la ruta.